# Can I use Serial.println() in a class?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I'm trying to convert a class header file from another c++ project to arduino, which in my mind involves replacing cout with Serial.println.

When I try to recomplile with all of these changes, I get this error from the compiler:

```
error: 'Serial' was not declared in this scope
     Serial.print(p[i]);
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

You have to `#include <Arduino.h>`, or compile with the `-include Arduino.h` flag. The Arduino IDE normally does that for you, but you have to do it yourself if you are working outside the IDE.

There are a couple of Arduino Makefiles floating around the Web which, just like the IDE, take care of this for you.

Comment: I'm actually using the Arduino IDE. :\

Comment: Are you compiling a .ino or a .cpp? If it's a .cpp, the IDE is probably not adding the #include. If it's a .ino, it may just have messed your code. In the IDE options, you can ask to see all the compile-time messages. This will show the g++ command-line and tell you if it's compiling your original source or a modified version. You will also see the paths of the temporary cpp files it's creating, check their contents, and see if it has broken something.